# The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found in the global namespace

Tags: xamarin

I just downloaded Xamarin (for windows). Created a new C#/Mobile Apps/Blank App (Xamarain.Forms Portable) solution. Tried to compile (I made no changes) and I get the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found in the global namespace
```

I guess I would expect this to compile out of the box so not sure why it's not.

```
namespace HelloWorld.Droid
{
    [Activity (Label = "HelloWorld.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity // this is the line that is erroring out on
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

            LoadApplication (new App ());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have more than one version of Visual Studio installed?

Comment: Exact same issue here. This is a disgrace and proof of absolute incompetence at Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing your Xamarin.Forms packages.

Can you expand your `Packages` directory in the Solution Explorer, and see if it's in there?

When you first create a new project, it'll go fetch it using NuGet.

If you don't see anything there, you can right-click the Packages folder, then choose Add Packages, and search for `Xamarin.Forms`.

Installing that should fix your problem.

Comment: That did it. Strange that it didn't automatically do that for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `Xamarin.Forms` from `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Package For Solution` and search `Xamarin.Forms` and install into your project.